# Unable to require local file ( node.js )

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am for some mysterious reason unable to require my local file. I have tried reinstalling node.js and moving the file to a different directory with no luck. What am I doing wrong?

[My file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrJtj.png)

[My index.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvqMm.png)

Comment: Look at the pathname, and now look at how you've spelled the folder name. JS is case-sensitive.

Comment: Right.... I must be legally blind D:

Comment: Love your passion for making the network load less in all of our popular load balancers working across continents! Let me add my part to clutter it up some more! xD

Comment: @PraveenThirumurugan :D :D :D

Comment: Technically, askers are supposed to post the code on this site in case third party sites go down, readers can view SO but not the third party, etc. Some corporations lock things down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `./YouTubeNotifier/yeet.js` should be replaced as `./YoutubeNotifier/yeet.js`. This should fix the issue.

***Bonus tip** - How do the program search for the files?*

1. It checks `node_modules` folder - `require('some-library');`
2. It checks the `path` - `require('./YoutubeNotifier/yeet.js');`

Comment: yup, I should probably go sleep now. As I'm making too many rookie mistakes at the moment lol